# SQL select two nearly fields

Tags: sql, select

How do I select two most nearly fields to specific timestamp?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'wp_weather' 
WHERE ( timestamp most nearly to 1385435000) AND city = 'Махачкала'
```

The table:

```
id | timestamp
---------------
 0 | 1385410000
 1 | 1385420000
 2 | 1385430000
 3 | 1385440000
 4 | 1385450000
```

Comment: By most nearly you mean closest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_weather
WHERE city = 'Махачкала'
order by abs(timestamp - 1385435000) 
limit 2
```

Comment: You beat me today for the second time! +1

Answer (score 3):

You may try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'wp_weather' 
WHERE city = 'Махачкала'
order by abs(timestamp - 1385435000) 
limit 2
```

Also check the [ABS function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)